# Function is kicking out variable with 3, separate lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

For the program I am writing my goal is to call a function, give it 2 values and then have it spit back lists based on those 2 numbers. Here's what I have so far,

```
import numpy as np


def list_maker (n, m):
    for n in range(n):

        l = list(np.random.randint(1,9, m))
        print(l)
```

My goal is to type "list_maker(3,5)" and have it output 3 lists, each with 5 elements. I want to keep using numpy so I can learn more about it rather than another type of operation. Whenever I call the function my out it,

```
list_maker(3,5)
[2, 7, 1, 5, 6]
[8, 5, 1, 3, 5]
[8, 2, 6, 3, 7]
```

However, I can not specifically change one element in one list, if I do l[0] = "Blank", all the elements at 0 position turn to blank and I can't do [0],[1]....
Any idea how to get an output like,

```
list_maker(3,5)
[[2, 7, 1, 5, 6],
[8, 5, 1, 3, 5],
[8, 2, 6, 3, 7]]
```

Where I can then specifically edit one element in one of the lists done by numpy?

Thank you for all the replies!

Comment: `[list(np.random.randint(1,9, m)) for _ in range(n)]` probably

Comment: Why exactly are you using numpy for this?

Comment: Im getting it data analysis using python and wanted to get my feet wet with numpy for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you want to *return* a list of lists. A simple list comprehension would work:

```
import numpy as np

def list_maker (n, m):
    return [list(np.random.randint(1,9, m)) for _ in range(n)]
```

then:

```
>>> list_maker(3,5)
[[1, 7, 2, 5, 7], [3, 5, 5, 7, 7], [8, 5, 1, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment your function is just printing the lists and not returning them.

And I'm not entirely sure of your intent; at the moment you're not creating a numpy array, but a list. More specifically, you're creating a list of 3 lists, not 3 separate lists.

You could create a numpy array by passing the `n, m` values directly to numpy's randint:

```
np.random.randint(1,9, size=(n, m))
```